# Identify and remove duplicates from a SQL table

Tags: sql

I have the following problem: I want to filter a list of clients based on their phone number.

My actual output:

```
id  firstname  lastname phonenumber creation date 
1      client    client   664433      2020/01/02
2      client    client   664433      2020/01/02
3      client    client   664432      2020/01/02
4      client    client   669433      2020/01/02
5      client    client   964433      2020/01/02
6      client    client   664033      2020/01/02
```

As you can see, there are phone numbers duplicated.

My desired output should be:

```
id  firstname  lastname phonenumber creation date 
1      client    client   664433      2020/01/02
2      client    client   664432      2020/01/02
3      client    client   669433      2020/01/02
4      client    client   964433      2020/01/02
5      client    client   664033      2020/01/02
```

Here is the code I'm using in order to identify these duplicated numbers and remove them from my output:

```
select 
cc.id ,
cc."FirstName", 
cc."LastName", 
cc."PhoneNumber" as phone_number,
case when cc."PhoneNumber" is not null count(cc."PhoneNumber") else 0,
cc."CreationDate"
from souscritootest.public.clients_crm cc
having count(cc."PhoneNumber") = 1
;
```

The problem is that I'm getting this feedback from the IDE: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "count"  Position: 128`

What I want to do is create a column with the case when to tag with a 1 if it's duplicated and 0 if it's not duplicated.

Thanks!

Comment: `count(cc."PhoneNumber")` does only count non-null values. I.e. no case expression needed.

Comment: `CASE WHEN [condition] THEN [value] ELSE [value] END`. But I don't understand why you feel you need the `CASE` expression, and I'm missing a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per phone number, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select cc.*
from (select cc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cc.PhoneNumber order by cc.CreationDate desc) as seqnum
      from souscritootest.public.clients_crm cc
     ) cc
where seqnum = 1;
```

I would also advise you to avoid double quotes for referring to columns and tables.  They just clutter queries.  Use identifiers that do not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

From What I Understand you have Two Problems

- Identify Phone Numbers which are duplicates
- Remove Duplicates

You can use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` like this

> `Select Count(*),PhoneNumber from YourTable GROUP BY PhoneNumber`

For duplicates Removal you can use unique constraint so your table does not get duplicate values for that column. But If you don't want to do that and find out discard duplicates you can try something like this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        contact_id, 
        first_name, 
        last_name, 
        email, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                first_name, 
                last_name, 
                email
            ORDER BY 
                first_name, 
                last_name, 
                email
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        sales.contacts
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```